# Error : Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses

Tags: asp.net, vbscript, include

This is the code in my aspx page.

```
<SCRIPT type="text/vbscript" RUNAT=server>
Public Function PriorPickText(acctnum, admitnum, thisTable, thisDescrip)
Dim priorShift, priorDate 
Dim str 
//perform the action
PriorPickText = str
End Function
</script>
```

I get an error like this : Method arguments must be enclosed in parentheses here :

```
Public Function PriorPickText(acctnum, admitnum, thisTable, thisDescrip)
Dim priorShift, priorDate
```

Can somebody help me with the error .?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Isn't it the `//perform the action` line that causes the error? Comments in VBScript / ASP are done with a single quote `'perform the action`.

Comment: On another thought, this error is caused by (what the script parser thinks it is) a function that is called without parenthesis like: `result = GetResult "arg1", "arg2"`

Comment: @AutomatedChaos : sorry..by mistake I gave '//'.Yes you are right.But I don't get where its missing the paranthesis

Comment: Ah, ok. This just came to me: You are using `asp.net`, this is in some ways different than classic asp or VBScript. In asp.net you need to surround every argument with parentheses even if you are calling a sub. See the difference between: `Response.Write "Nope, this is classic ASP"` and `Response.Write("Yes, this is how you use ASP.NET syntax")`. The error message you get is caused by some statement as seen in the first example.

Comment: There is no Response Statement in that page at all.I am actually converting an include file(.inc) in asp project to an aspx page .

Comment: It is not about the Response statement, it is about using the parenthesis the right way. In general: In vanilla `VBScript` you do not use parentheses around arguments for functions, subs and methods if you don't use `call` or the returned value; in `ASP.NET` _you always need to use parenthesis around arguments_. No matter how you are calling them.